# C# - Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> sorting is throwing System.ArgumentException

Tags: c#, sorting, dictionary, icomparable, argumentexception

I have an unsorted `Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>` and when trying to sort its value's Keys its throwing `System.ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.` Following is the function,

```
private static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> SortDictionary(Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>> unSortedDict)
{
      var sortedDict = (unSortedDict.OrderBy(entry => entry.Value.Keys)).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);

      return sortedDict;
}
```

I am attaching the data screen shot below where you can see the keys unsorted so you have an idea what i am trying to achieve, surly i am doing something wrong and i need your guidance, thanks

[image]

Comment: I need much better glasses to read the text in that screenshot ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dictionary is, by design, inherently unsorted.  If you sort the dictionary values, then convert it back to a Dictionary, you'll end up with an unsorted collection again.

That being said, the error is occuring because you're trying to call `OrderBy` with a [`KeyCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3fcwy8h6.aspx), which isn't a sortable type.

You may want to consider some other collection, such as a [`SortedDictionary<T,U>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx).  This will require writing a custom comparer to maintain the sort, however.

Comment: There is however a `SortedDictionary` that may suit your needs.